# create a new view for selected leads

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I need to select multiple leads in **"my open leads"** grid and I need to make a new Group for selected leads.Is Possible to do?

[image]

In This Screen shot,need to make a new group or view for selected records.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an out of the box way of selecting a list of records and adding them to a new view.  However you can create a personal view and manually select the records you want there.

You can get there by hitting the `Advanced Find` button on the ribbon, or by selecting the `View` tab and hitting the `New Personal View` button.

On that form you can select the records you want there.  Then you can Save As a new view.

Another option would be leveraging a custom relationship to the entity & user (or something like connections) and create a view to display records that you have a relationship to (or connection).  You would have to open the record first to add yourself, but once you did it would always show up.  It would be a good solution if that list doesn't change too often.

[image]